For which natural number $n$ is the sum of its positive divisors equal $n+6$?
I've found a solution, which is 6, since if we suppose n is a perfect number (whose sum of all positive divisors is 2n), we get this result. Are there more solutions, and if yes, how can i find them?

If you are talking about all divisors and not just proper ones, then this is fairly simple. We will always have $n$ and $1$ as divisors, so the sum of rest of the divisors must be $5$, and none of them can be $1$. The only possibility is $2$ and $3$, but if $n>6$ with $2$ and $3$ as divisors, then $6$ must also be a divisor, then the sum of divisors will exceed $5$, hence a contradiction. So the only possibility is $n=6$

Well the sum of all the divisors not including $n$ must add to $6$.  And the only sums of distinct terms that add to $6$.  And it must include $1$.  So that is only $1+5, 1+2+3$.  $1+5$ fails as $5$ is prime and if $n =5$ we did include $n$.  .... Be interesting to try this for $sum = n+k$ for a large $k$ like $12$ or something.... well $k =12$ is easy (none) but maybe a very divisible $k$.

@DevanshKamra  What's wrong with $n=25$?  The only proper divisor is $5$ so $\sigma_1(25)=1+5+25=31=25+6$.

@lulu My bad, I didn't consider the $0+5$ case, or the presence of only $1$ proper divisor.

@DevanshKamra  No worries.  Should add:  I'd say your answer (with the one minor correction) is worth posting as a solution, rather than as a comment.

Thank you everyone for the help, and yes, it would be great if you would write this out as an answer, so i can mark it as answer. Also for fleablood, the n+k case could be interesting, if k is "very divisible" aka some abundant number.

Considering all the possible positive divisors and not just proper ones, we can observe that $n$ and $1$ would always be divisors of $n$, thus the sum of remaining distinct proper divisors must be $5$. This gives us two cases:
Case I: Only one proper divisor exists for $n$, which must be $5$. So we need a number $n$ which has only $5$ as its proper divisor. Clearly, $n=25$.
Case II: Two proper divisors exist for $n$, which must be $2$ and $3$. One solution would be $n=6$. Now if $n>6$, then $2|n,\ 3|n\implies 6|n$, thus $6$ would also be a proper divisor, already greater than $5$, which gives a contradiction. Hence the only possible solution in this case is $n=6$
Note that since we cannot have the sum of more than two proper divisors to be $5$, we get $n=6$ and $n=25$ as the only possible solutions.

Oh... nice job thinking it further and not getting stuck on the "$5$ is a divisor but $n \ne 5$" trap.
